# how to update axes in guide - matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide, axes

i write a code using GUI and Mfile in MATHLAB. in my program i have a board.each time, computer put a marble and rotate the board then get a marble place and rotate direction of the board from user and After each of these things, i want it shows the result in axes1 in GUI. but it doesen't work in line 9 in the code below:

```
% some codes...
1.   while(currentDepth < 7)
2.   if(mod(currentDepth,2) ~= (plrC-1))
3.       plat(currentDepth);
4.       drawTable(); % show the result in axes1 --> it works
5.   else
6.       getMarble();
7.       drawTable(); % show the result in axes1 --> it works
8.       rotate();
9.       drawTable(); % show the result in axes1 --> it dosen't work
10.  end
11.  end
% some codes...
```

.

```
function drawTable()
global board;
% some codes...
imshow(board,[0 4]);
end
```

do you have any idea?

it's rotate function. th board is divided into 4 parts just 1 part rotates.

```
function rotate()
global board;
block = 0;
vector = 'non';
while(block<1 || block>4)
    block = str2double(cell2mat(inputdlg('chose a block: 1/2/3/4','board rotation')));
end
switch block
    case 1
        k=1; z=1;
    case 2
        k=1; z=4;
    case 3
        k=4; z=1;
    case 4
        k=4; z=4;
end
while(~strcmp(vector,'left') && ~strcmp(vector,'right'))
    vector = questdlg('rotate left or right','Rotation','left','right','right');
end
if(strcmp(vector,'left'))
    board(k:k+2,z:z+2)=rot90(board(k:k+2,z:z+2));
else
    board(k:k+2,z:z+2)=rot90(board(k:k+2,z:z+2),3);
end
end
```

ok now here we have a simplified code. make a new GUI with an axes then run the code below from 'OpeningFnc'. you will see my problem.

```
function test()
currentDepth = 1;
plrC = 1;
plrO = 2;
board = zeros(6);
while(currentDepth < 40)
    if(mod(currentDepth,2) == 1)
        plat();
        drawTable(); % show the result in axes1 --> it works
    else
        getMarble();
        drawTable(); % show the result in axes1 --> it works
        rotate();
        drawTable(); % show the result in axes1 --> it dosen't work
    end
    currentDepth = currentDepth +1;
end

function plat()
    for a=1:5000
       for b=1:5000
           for c=1:50
           m = a + b;
           end
       end
    end
    row = 1;
    column = 1;
    while(board(row,column) ~= 0)
        row = randi(6);
        column = randi(6); 
    end
    board(row,column) = plrC;
    row = randi([1 4]);
    column = randi([1 4]);
    board(row:row+2,column:column+2)=rot90(board(row:row+2,column:column+2));
end
function drawTable()

    board(board==0) = board(board==0)+4;
    B = zeros(305);
    B(:,152:154) = 3;
    B(152:154,:) = 3;
    for i=1:6
        for j=1:6
            x = (i*5)+1+(i-1)*45;
            y = (j*5)+1+(j-1)*45;
            B(x:x+44,y:y+44) = board(i,j);
        end
    end
    imshow(B,[0 4]);
    board(board==4) = board(board==4)*0;
end
function getMarble()

    board(board==0) = board(board==0)+4;
    b = zeros(305);
    b(:,152:154) = 3;
    b(152:154,:) = 3;
    for i=1:6
        for j=1:6
            x = (i*5)+1+(i-1)*45;
            y = (j*5)+1+(j-1)*45;
            b(x:x+44,y:y+44) = board(i,j);
        end
    end
    imshow(b,[0 4]);
    i = 0;
    while(i~=4)
        [x,y] = ginput(1);
        if(x<0 || x>305 || y<0 || y>305)
            i = 0;
        else
            i = b(ceil(y),ceil(x));
        end
    end
    y = ceil(y/50);
    x = ceil(x/50);
    board(y,x) = plrO;
end
function rotate()

    block = 0;
    vector = 'non';

    while(block<1 || block>4)
        block = str2double(cell2mat(inputdlg('chose a block: 1/2/3/4','board rotation')));
    end
    switch block
        case 1
            k=1; z=1;
        case 2
            k=1; z=4;
        case 3
            k=4; z=1;
        case 4
            k=4; z=4;
    end
    while(~strcmp(vector,'left') && ~strcmp(vector,'right'))
        vector = questdlg('rotate left or right','Rotation','left','right','right');
    end
    if(strcmp(vector,'left'))
        board(k:k+2,z:z+2)=rot90(board(k:k+2,z:z+2));
    else
        board(k:k+2,z:z+2)=rot90(board(k:k+2,z:z+2),3);
    end
end
```

end

Comment: Is that a custom rotate function? If so, provide the code

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "but it doesen't work in line 9 "? That is doesn't plot, that it plots something wrong, that it crashes, that it plots somewhere else

Comment: it doesn't show updated bord. it should show rotated board.

Comment: the board is rotated in line 8 but the new status not shown and Previous situation still appears until line 4 run again.

Comment: If you put something like `disp(board)` just before the `imshow` in the drawTable function, do you see the proper rotation happening?

Comment: yes.
i'm sure it rotates because when i run program without GUI it show the rotated board in a figure.

Comment: That is very strange, can you please make a minimal example that can reproduce the problem so we can help you trace the problem

Comment: ok. it takes some minutes.

Comment: I've simplified  program to give you a simple example but in this program every thing is ok and it works Properly. in my main program the function 'plat' have a Heavy performance so takes some seconds to execute. do you think it's why 'drawTable ' doesn't work?

Comment: I don't see why or how that might affect the draw function. Maybe you can add a dummy ‘plat‘ to the simple example with a big for loop just to see if that can replicate your problem

Comment: you can see the example code but the example code doesn't work just like original code. of curse it's not important. Please just concentrate on the main problem. 3th 'drawTable' doesn't work

Comment: At the end of `drawTable` add `drawnow`

Comment: yes. it works. THANK YOU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as [ThP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/192031/thp) said, i have to add drawnow() function at the end of drawTable.